# what means when awk $n param end with z?

Tags: awk

I have a shell script use awk from https://devconnected.com/monitoring-linux-processes-using-prometheus-and-grafana/.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
z=$(ps aux)
while read -r z
do
   var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3z}');
done <<< "$z"
echo $var
```

I know the $3 means the third matched string split by space. What is the `$3z` mean? Is `z` the param of `read -r z`? when I substitute `$3z` to `$3`, it changed nothing, why?

Comment: probably a typo, in string context uninitialized variable will be considered as empty string.. value of `$3` and `z` is being concatenated.. `read -r z` and `z` in the `awk` code are unrelated

Comment: I think it is not a typo, because the shell script source  https://devconnected.com/monitoring-linux-processes-using-prometheus-and-grafana/ tell me to change $3z to $4z.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: thank you very much, the `z` behind `$3` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that

- awk has no concatenation operator -- strings are concatenated by placing them side-by-side with optional whitespace in between
- awk variable names cannot begin with a number
- unset variables are substituted with the empty string in "string context" and with the value 0 in "numeric context"

This is concatenating the value of the 3rd field with the contents of the `z` variable.

Demo:

```sh
$ echo foo1 foo2 foo3 | awk 'BEGIN {z = "bar"} {print $3z}'
foo3bar
```